# JVectorMap Scroll Speed and Full screen Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am using JVectorMap to create a map Page on my Website. However I found that the scrolling zoom speed is much to slow. How do I adjust the scroll speed? There is no documentation for this issue. I found this:

```
zoomStep: 1.6,
```

This is however to specify the zoom step for the buttons, not the scrolling.

Another issue that I have found is that I cannot set the height of the Map Container to:

```
window.innerHeight;
```

But i can however set the width to:

```
window.innerWidth;
```

How can I specify to Height of the Map container to be in relation to the Window size? I've also tried using a % value.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be quite late answer, even might have been already answered somewhere.
But i got the same problem with mouse scroll speed and found the solution.
It can be fixed in js file in line 2382

```
zoomStep = Math.pow(1.003, event.deltaY);
```

You can easily change speed by changing that "1.003" value. More you make it - faster the scroll is.

I didnt fully understand the second problem of yours. But if it is about container height, I just use % values for the height. Make sure your parent has some height value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Re. the scroll speed I agree that it is far too slow in 2.0.1.

I had a look into the js file and found some comments on line 234 - " If this is an older event and the delta is divisable by 120, then we are assuming that the browser is treating this as an older mouse wheel event and that we should divide the deltas by 40 to try and get a more usable deltaFactor. Side note, this actually impacts the reported scroll distance in older browsers and can cause scrolling to be slower than native. Turn this off by setting $.event.special.mousewheel.settings.adjustOldDeltas to false.

On line 113 you will find the adjustOldDeltas set as true. I have set it as false but no change in the scroll speed.

Hopefully this works for you or gives you enough to explore the issue further.

W.