# jVectorMap mousewheel zooms in with too few steps

Tags: jvectormap

Zoom with the mousewheel in their main example http://jvectormap.com/

I have tried to change zoomScale property in the config, but that only seems to afflict the zoom buttons and not the mousewheel zoom.

I would prefer the mousewheel to zoom with the same amount of steps as the zoom buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bower package of jvectormap at https://github.com/tlvince/bower-jvectormap that's labeled as version 1.2.2 and here the mousewheel works as expected.

The problem still exists in all their demos on the website http://jvectormap.com/ and also in the latest downloadable code (2.0.1) in their official git repository https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap

Answer (score 1):

if its still needed, answered your question in other topic
[JVectorMap Scroll Speed and Full screen Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326531/jvectormap-scroll-speed-and-full-screen-issue)

Doubt that you can put the same step, but at least you can try to find value that will behave similarly to buttons.